# Putting two Pie Charts in one

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I am trying to create a pie chart with my following data in R:

```
    2009    2010
US  10  12
UK  13  14
Germany 18  11
China   9   8
Malaysia    7   15
Others  13  15
```

The command I am using is:

```
slices<-c(10,13,18,9,7,13,12,14,11,8,15,15)
 lbls <- c("US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others","US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others") 
 pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
 lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
 lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)
 pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),  main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

The figure that I am getting [image: is]

Now how can I configure the graph so that the countries have same colour scheme? and they follow the same order in two halves, like first it should be US and the UK and so on.

Two simplify the question I want to make two piecharts in one piechart, where one half of piechart represents 2009 and the other half 2010.

kindly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work.  At least the two halves have the same color scheme.  I am not sure what you mean by the same order.

```
slices<-c(10,13,18,9,7,13,12,14,11,8,15,15)
pct   <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)

lbls <- c("US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others","US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others") 
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)

col  <- c("yellow", "orange", "red", "purple", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "purple", "blue", "green")

pie(slices,labels = lbls,  main="Pie Chart of Countries", col = col)
```

You can shorten the `col` code with

```
col  <- rep(c("yellow", "orange", "red", "purple", "blue", "green"),2)
```

I am not certain what you want regarding the two halves.  If you want to standardize the percentages to 50% for each half this might work:

```
a <- c(7, 9, 12, 6, 5, 9)
a2 <- (a/sum(a)) * 50
a2
# [1]  7.291667  9.375000 12.500000  6.250000  5.208333  9.375000

b <- c(8, 10, 8, 6, 10, 10)
b2 <- (b/sum(b)) * 50
b2
# [1] 7.692308 9.615385 7.692308 5.769231 9.615385 9.615385

pct <- round(c(a2,b2),2)
pct
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, it does solves the problem of color scheme. But, how can I evenly divide the area into two half circles (or half pies) where one half has the representation of data in 2009 and the second half represents data of 2010.

Comment: Thank you for the check mark, but consider using @BenBolker's answer too.

Comment: @MarkMiller seen my answer? I'm curious what think of that approach

Comment: @Jaap I like it.  It looks nice.  I really like the labels, and your color assignment statement is clever and succinct.  I copied your code and Ben's and put it in my code library for future reference.

Comment: @MarkMiller Last one how can I make legend of labels instead of labeling them in figure itself

Answer (score 12):

```
 lbls0 <- c("US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others","US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others") 
 pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
 lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
 lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)
 pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),
      main="Pie Chart of Countries")


 nlbl <- length(lbls)
 yrs <- rep(2009:2010,each=nlbl/2)
 xlbls <- sprintf("%s (%d) %d%%",lbls0,yrs,pct)
 pie(slices,labels = xlbls, col=rep(rainbow(nlbl/2),2),
      main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

Would you be willing to consider a form of visualization that makes it easier to make quantitative comparisons?

```
 library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
 dd <- data.frame(lbls0,yrs,slices,pct)
 dd$lbls0 <- reorder(dd$lbls0,-dd$slices)
 ggplot(dd,aes(x=lbls0,y=slices,fill=lbls0))+
    geom_bar(aes(alpha=factor(yrs)),
                    stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width=1))+
    scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.7,1.0))+
    geom_text(aes(label=paste0(pct,"%"),
              group=interaction(lbls0,yrs)),hjust=-0.2,
              position=position_dodge(width=1))+
                  coord_flip()+
    expand_limits(y=20)+labs(x="",y="total")
```

[image]

If you're more interested in comparisons among countries within years rather than among years within countries, you could skip the `scale_alpha` stuff and use `facet_wrap(~yrs)` ...

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank's for the answer, as I am looking something in piecharts I won't be using bar charts. But your pie graphs are also great (+1). Thank you :)

Comment: I'd encourage you to read up on the [great pie chart debate](http://vizthinker.com/grudge-match-pie-chart-vs-bar-chart/) and form your own conclusions ...

Comment: +1 for answering the OP's question; +Awesomeness for leading them toward a better choice.

Comment: @BenBolker About the usefulness of pie-charts: this is also recognized in the help pages of R (see my answer for the quote).

Comment: yes, but there are arguments in both directions -- the Cleveland 1985 paper is far from the last word on the topic ...

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this with the help of the `reshape2` package:

```
# reading the data
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Country   2009    2010
US  10  12
UK  13  14
Germany 18  11
China   9   8
Malaysia    7   15
Others  13  15")

# setting the column names correct
colnames(df) <- c("Country","2009","2010")

# reshaping the dataframe
require(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id="Country")

# creating the plot
pie(df2$value, labels=paste0(df2$Country," (",df2$variable,") ",df2$value,"%"),
    col=rainbow(length(levels(df2$Country))), main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

which gives:
[image]

---

For a variation on the year-labels, you can also use:

```
pie(df2$value, labels=paste0(df2$Country," ",df2$value,"%"),
    col=rainbow(length(levels(df2$Country))), main="Pie Chart of Countries")
mtext("2009",side=3)
mtext("2010",side=1)
```

which gives:
[image]

---

As @BenBolker said, pie-charts are not a very good way of presenting data. It's worth quoting the help page `?pie` were this is recognized as well:

> Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information. The eye is good at judging linear measures and bad at judging relative areas. A bar chart or dot chart is a preferable way of displaying this type of data.
>
> Cleveland (1985), page 264: “Data that can be shown by pie charts always can be shown by a dot chart. This means that judgements of position along a common scale can be made instead of the less accurate angle judgements.” This statement is based on the empirical investigations of Cleveland and McGill as well as investigations by perceptual psychologists.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution which was similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748069/ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot/26749522#26749522)

```
slices <- c(10,13,18,9,7,13,12,14,11,8,15,15)
lbls <- c("US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others","US","UK","Germany","China", "Malaysia", "Others") 
pct  <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)


dat <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2009, 2010), each = 6), lbls, slices)
dat$total <- with(dat, ave(slices, year, FUN = sum))


plot.new()

par(new = TRUE)
pie(dat$slices, border = NA, radius = 1,
    col = rainbow(length(lbls) / 2), labels = lbls,
    main = 'Pie Chart of Countries')

par(new = TRUE)
c2 <- c('grey50', 'grey75')[factor(dat$year)]
pie(dat$slices, border = c2, radius = .7, col = c2, labels = NA)

text(0, c(.3, -.3), 2009:2010)
```

[image]