# Need to convert File data into parameters for making a pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

Currently having a difficult time with this error. I am relatively new to R and still working out the kinks but here what I am trying to do.

I have a file that has this exact format:

```
2j2j 902223
6i2i 2311
0i2b 23345
1k2c 4324
```

I want to convert this into a pie chart in R, but I am having a difficult time putting everything where it needs to be. I want the first column to be the labels, and the second column to be the data that is that being visualized. The methodology I am using putting each column into its own variable. I am extremely confused what would be effective, a `scan()` function or a `read.table` function?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with? Did you try `read.table(path_to_your_file)`? Can you show some code of what you've tried? Furthermore, are you sure you want a piechart? They are notoriously hard to interpret.

Comment: Initially having a function read a data file and spliting each column into it own variable. I've got the pie function figured out, now I'm stuck on this portion.

Comment: Please don't make a pie chart with R. Leave that for the Excel users. The `waffle` package presents a much better alternative. So do bar charts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is stored in a file named "temp.dat" you could use

```
mydat <- read.table("temp.dat")
#> mydat
#    V1     V2
#1 2j2j 902223
#2 6i2i   2311
#3 0i2b  23345
#4 1k2c   4324
pie(mydat$V2,labels=mydat$V1)
```

for a simple pie chart. The result is not very pretty, for the reasons pointed out by @Heroka in the comments.

[image]

Of course, one could try to embellish it by [changing the colors or using a 3D representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594642/beautiful-pie-charts-with-r), but this will probably not improve significantly the understanding of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Before I build an example, please remember that pie charts are *not recommended* in the R documentation. The authors recommend bar or dot plots, mainly because people are able to judge length better than volume.

Say that, first, you should have, for example a dataframe with observations. In this case, I create a dataframe df with 400 vehicles:

```
df <- data.frame(400)
df <- rep( c("car", "truck", "other", "bike", "suv"), c(60, 120, 20, 50, 150))
```

Since pie charts are especially useful for proportions, let's have a look on the proportions of our vehicles, than we will report on the graph in this case:

```
paste(prop.table(table(df))*100, "%", sep = "")
[1] "15%"   "5%"    "30%"   "12.5%" "37.5%"
```

Then you can draw your pie chart,

```
pie(table(df), labels = paste(round(prop.table(table(e3))*100), "%", sep = ""), 
col = heat.colors(5), main = "Vehicles proportions - n: 400")
```

[image]

Finally, you can add it a legend:

```
legend("topright", legend = c("car", "truck", "other", "bike", "suv"), 
fill = heat.colors(5), title = "Categories", cex = 0.5)
```