# How to label pie chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, pie-chart, geom-text

Despite my better efforts as an R newcomer, I can't seem to figure out how to label the slices of a pie chart created with ggplot2.

I have a data.frame (tibble) that I need to filter by "Sample" and plot  as separate pie charts. The data looks like this (including "lab.ypos" which I add in an effort to map my geom_text locations (see failed code):

```
# A tibble: 30 x 4
   Sample Source_Names Relative_Contribution lab.ypos
   <chr>  <chr>                        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 FH3    CMB                           81.4     40.7
 2 FH3    SM                             2.2     82.5
 3 FH3    Uinta                         16.4     91.8
 4 SC1    CMB                           72.4     36.2
 5 SC1    SM                             7       75.9
 6 SC1    Uinta                         20.5     89.6
 7 5-SC   CMB                           68.6     34.3
 8 5-SC   SM                             0.7     69.0
 9 5-SC   Uinta                         30.8     84.7
10 PL3    CMB                            1.6      0.8
```

I've managed to get an appropriate lookin chart without labels, but as soon as I try to calculate label positions for my filtered data sets, it all fails.

```
# round data to 1 decimal place and add label position
DZmix_all_edit <- DZmix_all %>% 
  mutate(Relative_Contribution=round(Relative_Contribution,1)) %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(Relative_Contribution) - 0.5*Relative_Contribution)
```

```
# subset data 
DZmix.FH3 <- filter(DZmix_all_edit, Sample == "FH3")
```

```
# define color scheme
  # SM = "#cccccc", Uinta = "#969696", CMB = "#636363"
DZmix.colrs <- c("#636363", "#cccccc", "#969696")
```

```
# Black and White pie plots 
ggplot(DZmix.FH3, aes(x = "", y = Source_Names, fill = factor(Source_Names))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = DZmix.colrs) +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = Relative_Contribution), color = "white")+
  labs(fill="Potential Source", 
       x=NULL, 
       y=NULL, 
       title=NULL, 
       caption=NULL) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0)
```

The expectation is that I get a pie plot with each slice labeled with "Relative_Contribution" in the middle of the slice. What happens, however, is only a fraction of a pie chart that may or may not be labeled correctly.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: It seems plotly does a better job at labeling pie charts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436214/ggplot-pie-chart-labeling