# In a pie graph for R, how do I place the names of each group/slice within the slices so that I don't need a legends tab?

Tags: r, pie-chart

Here's the code:

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Freq = c(548, 326, 292, 199, 138)
)

dummy %>%
  mutate(perc =scales::percent(Freq/sum(Freq))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Var1)) %>%
  mutate(pos = cumsum(Freq)- Freq/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = factor(Var1) )) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = perc), size=5, show.legend = F, nudge_x = 1) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Group"))
```

And here's the graph:
[image]

Is there a way to make it so that instead of having a legends tab, the names of each slice is placed within the slices in the pie graph itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436214/ggplot-pie-chart-labeling

Comment: add `geom_text(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = Var1))` in code.

Comment: @Park is there a way to arrange the text so that they run alongside the slices? (instead of horizontally, since that makes the text overflow into other slices and overlap with other text)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to understand what you want.

```
dummy %>%
  mutate(perc =scales::percent(Freq/sum(Freq))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Var1)) %>%
  mutate(pos = cumsum(Freq)- Freq/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = factor(Var1) )) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = perc), size=5, show.legend = F, nudge_x = 1) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Group")) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1.6, label=Var1),
           position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm asking how to make the labels "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" rotated so that they are running alongside the same direction each slice is pointing at. Because my actual code (which I don't want to post here) has labels that are not just a single letter. The way my code is right now, the labels for each slice are overlapping with each other because they are all horizontal.

Comment: @Macromind101 As I said in your previous question, since you didn't provide a reproducible example, it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: is there a way for me to PM you? Since again, I don't want to make my code public

Comment: @Macromind101 Please follow [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide an example data, and precise problem.