# ggplot2 pie chart working as standalong code but not as a custom function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing a custom function to make pie charts with `ggplot2`. The code I have written works just fine, but when I start it using inside function body, it stops working. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```r
dataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(gender = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male"),
                           pet = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog")))

library(dplyr)

## as standalone code

df <- dplyr::group_by_(dataframe, .dots = c('gender', 'pet')) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(perc))

ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill', aes(fill = factor(pet))) +
  facet_wrap(~gender, labeller = "label_both") +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), fill = factor(pet)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    color = 'black',
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

```r
## as custom function

ggpiecustom <- function(data, condition, main) {

df <- dplyr::group_by_(data, .dots = c(condition, main)) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(perc))

ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill', aes(fill = factor(main))) +
  facet_wrap(condition, labeller = "label_both") +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), fill = factor(main)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    color = 'black',
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
}

ggpiecustom(data = dataframe, condition = 'gender', main = 'pet')
```

[image]

Created on 2018-01-19 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Assign your ggplot object to a variable and then use `plot(variable)`.

Comment: But the main problem is still ggplot2's strange evaluation rules. `fill` is still `factor(main)` and not the contents of `main` converted to a factor.

Comment: @Freguglia I did assign `ggplot` object to `p` and then used either `return(p)` or `plot(p)` inside custom function, but none of it worked. I get the same, unicolor plot.

Comment: The custom function is just trying to save you from a bad visualization choice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594642/beautiful-pie-charts-with-r/33595456#33595456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ggplot is, inside your function, seeing `factor('pet')` and assigning the same value of `pet` for everyone. Use `get(main)` to specify you want the object with the name specified in main.

```
dataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(gender = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male"),
                                 pet = c("dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog")))


ggpiecustom <- function(data, condition, main) {

  df <- dplyr::group_by_(data, .dots = c(condition, main)) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(perc))

  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
    geom_col(position = 'fill', aes(fill = factor(get(main)))) +
    facet_wrap(condition, labeller = "label_both") +
    geom_label(
      aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), fill = factor(get(main))),
      position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
      color = 'black',
      size = 5,
      show.legend = FALSE
    ) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
}

ggpiecustom(data = dataframe, condition = 'gender', main = 'pet')
```