# Why I'm having condition error plotting pie chart?

Tags: r, pie-chart

Maybe someone can tell me why I'm getting an error

```
Error in if (df.name %in% dfs) { : the condition has length > 1
```

while trying to plot pie chart using function PieChart from lessR package? Here's a code I'm trying

```
PieChart(level, values = "%", color = "white", data = as.data.frame(mutate(data, level = case_when(`param num` < 10 ~ "low", `param num` >= 10 ~ "high"))), fill = c("blue", "violet"))
```

I used to run this code before and it was fine but I've changed laptop and reinstalled R & RStudio. But I'm opening the original folder with project that I had on old laptop. So that can't be the issue, can it?

***Update***. Example for iris dataset - getting the same mistake

```r
library(lessR)
PieChart(sepal.length.level, values = "%", color = "white", data = as.data.frame(mutate(iris, sepal.length.level = case_when(Sepal.Length < 6 ~ "low", Sepal.Length >= 6 ~ "high"))), fill = c("orange", "green"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey I've updated the question, please take a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beautiful Pie Charts with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594642/beautiful-pie-charts-with-r)

Comment: A pie chart [may not be your best option](https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/pie.html).

Comment: I want a pie chart exactly. And I like the way it was, just what I needed. Now I have a error, and my question is how to fix that error. not what plot should I build.

Comment: My link to "beautiful pie charts in R" should give you your solution.  My link to the disadvantages of pie charts was purely advisory.  You are, of course,  free to ignore it if you wish.