# Two-layer donut chart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need a two-layer donut chart. I prepared draft in Excel (with two plots overlayed). But there are so many problems with Excel charts - so I decided to go for R and ggplot.

My data set looks like this:

```
inheritance gene count
Autosomal dominant Autosomal dominant 4
Autosomal recessive Autosomal recessive 4
X-linked X-linked 3
De-novo ATP1A3 1
De-novo CDKL5 1
De-novo GABRB3 1
De-novo GABRG2 1
De-novo GRIN2B 1
De-novo HCN1 1
De-novo KCNQ2 5
De-novo MEF2C 1
De-novo PURA 1
De-novo SCN1A 2
De-novo SCN2A 2
De-novo SCN8A 1
De-novo WDR45 3
```

Inner circle is has only four classes:

```
Autosomal recessive, Autosomal dominant, Xlinked and Denovo
```

Outer circle has subsetted Denovo into Gene count (other classes are not divided).

Here is my draft from excel:
[image: Desired plot]

Could somebody give me any advice how to perform something like this? I tried examples in plotly, ggplot2 and plotrix but without success.

Comment: [Here is a good start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748069/ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot).