# How to visualize the group and subgroup frequency?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I have to plot the frequency data using a group variable `As` and subgroup variable `ADs`. What is the best way to visualize the frequency ie., pie chart or mosaic? Is there any function available in ggplot2?

```
df <- data.frame(As=c('GeA','GeA','GeA', 'GA'), 
             ADs=c('A44','A33','A37','A141'),
             freq=c(501,65,50,103))

#    As  ADs freq
# 1 GeA  A44  501
# 2 GeA  A33   65
# 3 GeA  A37   50
# 4  GA A141  103
```

Some thoughts are like below:

[image: image1]

However, is there any way to differentiate both group and subgroup in a single plot?

Out of the proposed solutions, below [two charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44850132/4836511) looked promising.

Pie Chart & Tile Graph

[image: piechart][image: tileGraph]

I have used the following code suggested by M--.

```
df.2 <- df
df.2$ymax <- with(df.2, ave(freq, As, FUN=cumsum))
df.2$ymin <- lag(df.2$ymax, default = 0)
df.2$ymin <- ifelse(lag(as.character(df.2$As), default = 0) != df.2$As, 0, df.2$ymin)

df.legend <- df.2[with(df.2, order(As)), ]

library(ggplot2)
# Pie Chart
ggplot(df.2) + 
  geom_rect(aes(fill=As, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill=ADs, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=3, xmin=0)) +
  xlim(c(0, 4)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=1) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,3), labels=c("ADs", "As")) + 
  annotate("text", x=rep(1.5,4), y=c(50, 350,530,590), 
           label= as.character(df.legend$ADs)) + 
  annotate("text", x=rep(3.5,2), y=c(50, 350), 
           label= as.character(unique(df.legend$As))) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

# Tile Graph
ggplot(df.2) + 
  geom_rect(aes(fill=As, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill=ADs, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=3, xmin=0)) +
  xlim(c(0, 4)) + theme(aspect.ratio=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1.5,3.5), labels=c("ADs", "As")) + 
  annotate("text", x=rep(1.5,4), y=c(50, 350,530,590), 
           label= paste(as.character(df.legend$ADs), df.legend$freq,sep= " = ")) + 
  annotate("text", x=rep(3.5,2), y=c(50, 350), 
           label= as.character(unique(df.legend$As))) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

However, I didn't get the same output

Pie Chart & Tile Graph

[image: piechart_err] [image: tileGraph_err]

Message: Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.

Could you please advise what would be the issue? Is there any difference in the version of the package(s) used?

Comment: stacked bar plot

Comment: I am not getting a clear picture on how to visualize both group and subgroup using the stacked bar plot. Could you draw roughly and share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Stacked Barplot:

You can use stacked barplots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = As, y = freq, fill = ADs)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

you can add this and get labels on the plot:

```
p +   geom_text(aes(label = paste(ADs, freq, sep=": ")), 
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) + #subgroups
       stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = ..y.., group = As), geom = "text") + #groups
        theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Next two answers are in reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748069/ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot).

## Tile Graph:

For this we need to tweak the data:

```
  df.2 <- df
  df.2$ymax <- with(df.2, ave(freq, As, FUN=cumsum))
  df.2 <- df.2[with(df.2, order(As)), ]
  
  #for some reason lag function does not work properly in R 3.3.3
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df.2)[, ymin:=c(0,ymax[-.N])]  

  
  df.legend <- df.2[with(df.2, order(As)), ]
```

Then we can use `ggplot` again:

```
 ggplot(df.2) + 
   geom_rect(aes(fill=As, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3)) +
   geom_rect(aes(fill=ADs, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=3, xmin=0)) +
   xlim(c(0, 4)) + theme(aspect.ratio=1) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1.5,3.5), labels=c("ADs", "As")) + 
   annotate("text", x=rep(1.5,4), y=c(50, 350,530,590), 
          label= paste(as.character(df.legend$ADs), df.legend$freq,sep= " = ")) + 
   annotate("text", x=rep(3.5,2), y=c(50, 350), 
        label= as.character(unique(df.legend$As))) + 
      theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(),
     axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

## Pie Chart:

```
ggplot(df.2) + 
 geom_rect(aes(fill=As, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3)) +
 geom_rect(aes(fill=ADs, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=3, xmin=0)) +
 xlim(c(0, 4)) + 
 theme(aspect.ratio=1) +
 coord_polar(theta="y") +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,3), labels=c("ADs", "As")) + 
 annotate("text", x=rep(1.5,4), y=c(50, 350,530,590), 
        label= as.character(df.legend$ADs)) + 
 annotate("text", x=rep(3.5,2), y=c(50, 350), 
        label= as.character(unique(df.legend$As))) + 
 theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(),
     axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the plot. It would be nice to see the share of each subgroup.

Comment: Can you please post the package version of ggplot2 you are using? For some reason, I'm not getting colors for last two plots.

Comment: @Prradep Edit your question. Add the result that you get, so it can be reopened. I will add my session info and package versions ASAP.

Comment: I have found the reason why I'm not getting the same output and it is due to the `ymin` values. After changing the values(`df.legend$ymin <- c(0,103,501,566)`), I have got the output. Please edit the answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: otherwise using `lag` function on the `df.legend` would give the desired output!

Comment: @Prradep I used `data.table` package. It does work on my other machine but not on my laptop either. Not sure what exactly has happened to `lag` function. But now this addresses your question.