# Changing the position of the label in a donut chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am trying to move the position of the label in a donut chart to be at the right side of the chart but I am not able to do it. I am using ggplot and ggrepel to make the graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

expenditurePie = data.frame(
  value = c(98,2),
  area = c("A","B"),
  label = c("","This is a label"))

ggplot(expenditurePie, aes(y=value, fill = area, label = label)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = 4), stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 5, x= 4, point.padding = unit(1.8, "lines"), direction = "x") +
  xlim(0.5, 4.5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=0.5, y=0, label = "24 444", size = 16, color = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "grey", B = "black")) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

The image below is the result of the code above:
[image]

But the image below shows what I need:
[image]

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: `nudge_x` seems as if it may work here

Comment: ... and not to forget this beautiful plot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748069/ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot?26749522#26749522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is an option for you. Instead of relying on the magic of `ggrepel` my approach sets the label manually (still using `ggrepel` but with force set to 0) and while drawing the segment using `geom_segement`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

expenditurePie = data.frame(
  value = c(98,2),
  area = c("A","B"),
  label = c("","This is a label"))

ggplot(expenditurePie, aes(y = value, fill = area, label = label)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = 4), stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 5, x = 7, point.padding = unit(1.8, "lines"), direction = "x", force = 0, seed = 42) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 4.6, xend = 5.5, y = 1, yend = 1)) +
  xlim(0.5, 5.5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=0.5, y=0, label = "24 444", size = 20, color = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "grey", B = "black")) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? Utilizing `nudge_x=5`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

expenditurePie = data.frame(
  value = c(98,2),
  area = c("A","B"),
  label = c("","This is a label"))

ggplot(expenditurePie, aes(y=value, fill = area, label = label)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = 4), stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 5, x= 4, point.padding = unit(1.8, "lines"), 
direction = "x", nudge_x = 5) +
  xlim(0.5, 4.5) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=0.5, y=0, label = "24 444", size = 16, color = 
"grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "grey", B = "black")) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]