# How to put labels in the center of the pieces of the inner (main) group of the donut (pie function from graphics package r)

Tags: r, donut-chart

I'm trying to improve the `piedonut` function I copied from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748069/ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot). The problem is to put labels in the center of the pieces of the inner (main) group of the donut. Here's an example for better understanding.

```r
piedonut <- function(x_outer, 
                     group_inner=NULL, 
                     labels_inner=NULL,
                     labels_outer=NULL,  
                     border_outer=NULL,
                     col=NULL, 
                     col_labels_inner=NULL,
                     radius = c(.7, 1)){
  group <- rep_len(group_inner, 
                   length(x_outer))
  ug  <- unique(group)
  tbl <- table(factor(group, 
                      levels=ug))

  col <- if (is.null(col)){
    seq_along(ug)
    }else{
    rep_len(col, length(ug))
    }
  col.main <- Map(rep, 
                  col[seq_along(tbl)], 
                  tbl)
  col.sub  <- lapply(col.main, 
                     function(x){
                       al <- head(seq(0, 1, length.out = length(x) + 2L)[-1L], 
                                  -1L)
                       Vectorize(adjustcolor)(x, alpha.f = al)
   }
  )

  plot.new()

  ##OUTER PLOT -> Donut
  par(new=TRUE)
  pie(x_outer, 
      border=border_outer, 
      radius=radius[2L],
      col=unlist(col.sub), 
      labels=labels_outer)

  ##INNER PLOT -> Pie
  par(new=TRUE)
  x_aux <- split(x_outer,
                 rep(1:3,c(tbl)))
  x_aux1 <- lapply(x_aux,
                   mean)
  x_aux2 <- unlist(x_aux1)
  x_mean <- c(0,cumsum(x_aux2)/sum(x_aux2))
  nx <- length(x_aux)
  
  twopi <- 2*pi
  
  t2xy <- function(t) {
          t2p <- twopi * t
          list(x = radius[1L] * cos(t2p), 
               y = radius[1L] * sin(t2p))
  }
  
  pie(x_outer, 
      border=NA, 
      radius=radius[1L],
      col=unlist(col.main), 
      labels=NA)
  if(is.null(labels_inner)){
    labels_inner <- ug
  }
  if(is.null(col_labels_inner)){
    col_labels_inner <- 1:nx
  }
  for(i in 1L:nx){
     P <- t2xy(mean(x_mean[i + 0:1]))
     text((0.35 * P$x), 
          (0.35 * P$y), 
          labels_inner[i], 
          xpd=TRUE,
          adj=0.5,
          col=col_labels_inner)
     #points(1.1*P$x, 1.1*P$y,col='red',size=5)                    
 }   
}

dados <- structure(list(fatind = c("NHOMICIDIO", 
"NOCORRENCIAS", "IDH", "IVS", "DENSIDADE", "NPRISAOFLAGRANTE", 
"NTCO", "POLI_HAB"), percind = c(0.75, 0.25, 0.333, 0.167, 0.5, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.4), group = c("est_cri", "est_cri", "ind_socioec", 
"ind_socioec", "ind_socioec", "prod_pol", "prod_pol", "prod_pol"
), percgroup = c(0.273, 0.273, 0.273, 0.273, 0.273, 0.455, 0.455, 
0.455)), row.names = c(46L, 47L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 10L, 11L, 12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Notice that the sum of the percentages (`percind`) within the "group" `factor` adds up to one and the percentage (`percgroup`) sum of the groups sums up to one.

```r
with(dados,
     piedonut(x_outer=percind, 
              group_inner=group,
              labels_outer=fatind,
              labels_inner=unique(dados$group),
              col_labels_inner='white',
              border_outer='black'))
```