# Creating a Nested Pie Chart from Two Dataframes

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I am new to R and I am trying to create a nested pie/donut chart in plotly. The outer pie chart would be # of sales by category, the inner pie chart would be # of sales by subcategory of the larger categories. (e.g. the "Furniture" category is made up of sub-categories like "Chairs","Tables",etc..)

I have no trouble creating individual pie charts of each type. However, when trying to nest them together I am running into issues. I believe this is because they are created from two different data frames: "category_values" and "sub_category_values". However, both data frames are subsets of the same data frame called "salesData"

I will be providing code samples below to view, if you'd like, the data I am working with can be downloaded at https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rohitsahoo/sales-forecasting/data

Here's a sample of my code that produces an error, the program cannot see the "total_sales_in_subcategory" because it only exists in the "sub_category_values" data frame, not the "category_values" data frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
options(scipen = 999)

#reading in sales data
salesData <-  read.csv("train.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#subsetting sales data
category_values <- salesData %>%
                      group_by(Category) %>%
                        mutate(total_sales_in_category = sum(Sales)) %>%
                          distinct(Category, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
                            arrange(desc(total_sales_in_category))

sub_category_values <- salesData %>%
                          group_by(Category,Sub.Category) %>%
                            mutate(total_sales_in_subcategory = sum(Sales)) %>%
                              distinct(Sub.Category, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
                                arrange(desc(total_sales_in_subcategory))


#creating plot
plot_ly(category_values) %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~Category,values = ~total_sales_in_category,
          type = 'pie',hole=0.7,sort=F,
          marker = list(line = list(width=2))) %>%
  add_pie(sub_category_values,labels = ~Sub.Category,values = ~total_sales_in_subcategory,
          domain = list(x = c(0.15,0.85),
                        y = c(0.15,0.85)),
                      sort = F)
```

Error output:

```
Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : 
  object 'total_sales_in_subcategory' not found
```

I have managed to get about halfway to where I want to be by using this method:

```
#creating plot method 2
plot2 <- plot_ly(category_values) %>%
  add_pie(category_values,labels = ~Category, values = ~total_sales_in_category,hole=0.7,name="Category",sort = F,type='pie')

plot1 <- plot_ly(sub_category_values) %>%
  add_pie(sub_category_values,labels = ~Sub.Category,values = ~total_sales_in_subcategory,hole=0.7,name = "Sub-Category",domain = list(x = c(0.15,0.85),y=c(0.15,0.85),sort=F))

combined_plot <- subplot(plot1, plot2, nrows = 1, margin = 0.03) %>%
  layout(layout)

combined_plot
```

This ouputs a good looking nested donut chart with all the correct values, however, they are not matched up correctly. For example, the "Paper" subcategory is aligned under the "Technology" category rather than the "Office Supplies" category. Here's the ouput:
[image]

One idea I have for a possible solution is to not separate salesData into two data frames, but create 1 data frame that contains both "total_sales_in_category" and "total_sales_in_subcategory" variables. Perhaps that way I can create a nested pie chart using the first method I showed.

However, I am a bit lost as to how I would go about that, as I've pigeonholed myself into this 2 data frame line of thinking and am having trouble thinking outside of the box.

I can't picture in my head the format of a plotly that would achieve what I am looking to do from 1 data frame. Since both of my subsetted data sets do so much heavy lifting in terms of filtering/mutating the data to fit my needs for a pie chart. Without subsetting, I can't picture how I would sum sales by category or subcategory, or take only unique values, etc... all of that is being done in the subsetting blocks.

Comment: `webr::PieDonut()` ? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67829312/646761

Comment: @margusl That worked for me! Thank you! I'm still open to other answers just because the result doesn't look the best and I'd prefer to achieve this in plotly. Also, I want to display real numbers as well as percentages.

For anyone else that wants to give webr a try, here's my code:

PieDonut(sub_category_values, aes(Category, Sub.Category, count=total_sales_in_subcategory),
         title = "% sales by category",
         ratioByGroup = FALSE)