# How can I put the labels outside of piechart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

How can I put the label outside the pie chart So that labels will be in the proper place?

```
Product <- c("Product1","Product2","Product3","Product4","Product5","Product6","Product7")
Value <- c(1000000,200002,599996,1399994,2199992,2999990,3799988)
df <- data.frame(Product,Value)
df$Label <- paste(Product, paste(round(((df$Value/sum(df$Value))*100),2),"%"), sep="-")

library(ggplot2)

p <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = Value, fill = Product)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p <- p + coord_polar(theta = 'y') + theme_void()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = Label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(end = 2 * pi * cumsum(Value)/sum(Value),
         start = lag(end, default = 0),
         middle = 0.5 * (start + end),
         hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 1, 0),
         vjust = ifelse(middle < pi/2 | middle > 3 * pi/2, 0, 1))

library(ggforce) # for 'geom_arc_bar'
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                   start = start, end = end, fill = Product)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.05 * sin(middle), y = 1.05 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.5),  # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1.1),    # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                     name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks! That's what I want !

Comment: @Let'sYo  Glad I could help. You could also use baseplotting to achieve that, [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984219/2204410)

Comment: Thanks for your addition information...
i just spend hours to find out putting the label outside the pie chart but there is not much useful link for me to go through
maybe it's because my bad key-words
anyway thanks again!

Comment: Hm, where is the label for Product1?

Comment: @untill Thx for spotting. I adjusted the limits in the `scale_*_continuous` functions a bit; now all labels fit in the plot. See the update.

Answer (score 3):

Besides solution by @Jaap, it can also be achieved adding `theme` and `scale_y_continuous` to you basic plot `p`.

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=1,y=Value,fill=Product))+geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black")

p <- p + coord_polar(theta='y')+ theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                                       axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                       axis.text.x=element_text(colour='black'),
                                       axis.title=element_blank())
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=cumsum(df$Value) - df$Value / 2, labels= df$Label)
```

The Result is as following :
[image: pe-plot]

Comment: Thx so much! I will try it later on!

Comment: @Let'sYo, just added an alternative as pie-chart of previous one is missing a label `Product1-8.2%`

Answer (score 2):

I tried to include the label for product 1 in @Jaap's code. I changed x and y value in the geom_text and it worked. Everything else in the code is the same.

```
geom_text(aes(x = 1 * sin(middle), y = 1 * cos(middle), label = Label,
            hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust))
```