# ggplot label pie chart - next to pie pieces - legend incorrect

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using the following code

```
education_bachelor_summary<- education_bachelor %>%
  group_by(title_mapped) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(label=(str_c(title_mapped, "-", as.character(percent(perc)), sep=" ")))


midpoint <-sum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) - cumsum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) + education_bachelor_summary$perc/2

ggplot(education_bachelor_summary, aes(x = "", y=perc, fill = factor(title_mapped))) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=midpoint, labels=education_bachelor_summary$label) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1) +
  labs(fill="Bachelor/ Vordiplom",x=NULL,y=NULL,title="",caption="") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())
```

which generates the following plot
[image]

### Issues

1. Labels next to pie pieces are **cut off**.
2. labels on pie pieces are correct, but labels on right-hand side are mixed up, "Informatik" and "Mathe" are switched.

### Code to reproduce example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
education_bachelor_summary <- structure(list(title_mapped = c("BWL","Mathe", "Informatik", "VWL", "Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen"), n = c(82L, 37L, 33L, 10L, 5L), perc = c(0.491017964071856, 0.221556886227545, 0.197604790419162, 0.0598802395209581, 0.029940119760479), label = c("BWL - 49.1%", "Mathe - 2.2%", "Informatik - 19.8%", "VWL - 6.0%", "Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen - 3.0%")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
midpoint <-sum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) - cumsum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) + education_bachelor_summary$perc/2

ggplot(education_bachelor_summary, aes(x = "", y=perc, fill = factor(title_mapped))) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=midpoint, labels=education_bachelor_summary$label) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1) +
  labs(fill="Bachelor/ Vordiplom",x=NULL,y=NULL,title="",caption="") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())
```

**More generally I am looking to enhance my pie chart. I would like a pie chart with readable labels next to each piece of pie.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put the labels outside of piechart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184645/how-can-i-put-the-labels-outside-of-piechart)

Comment: I would disagree, I already have labels next to my pie chart. My main issue is that they are cut off and you cannot read the whole label. Something you can also see in the question's answer you linked. Should I rephrase to make this more clear?

Comment: The accepted answer on that post doesn't spell it out, but they adjust the limits of both the x- and y-axes to make room for long text labels, which would likely solve your issue with labels being cut off

Comment: Thanks I will try that, as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the legend is wrong and your manually added chart labels are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color order is different between fill and legend, because you define them separately. The legend color is defined in `scale_y_continuous(breaks=midpoint, labels=education_bachelor_summary$label)`, while the fill color depends on the order that `factor(title_mapped)` places them in. `factor()` orders them alphabetically by default if the input is a character vector.

To fix this, you can create a factor for `fill` value yourself as shown below.

```
library(tidyverse)
 library(scales)
 education_bachelor_summary <- structure(list(title_mapped = c("BWL","Mathe", "Informatik", "VWL", "Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen"), n = c(82L, 37L, 33L, 10L, 5L), perc = c(0.491017964071856, 0.221556886227545, 0.197604790419162, 0.0598802395209581, 0.029940119760479), label = c("BWL - 49.1%", "Mathe - 2.2%", "Informatik - 19.8%", "VWL - 6.0%", "Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen - 3.0%")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
 midpoint <-sum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) -  cumsum(education_bachelor_summary$perc) + education_bachelor_summary$perc/2
 education_bachelor_summary$fill <- factor(education_bachelor_summary$title_mapped, levels=education_bachelor_summary$title_mapped)

 ggplot(education_bachelor_summary, aes(x = "", y=perc, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=midpoint, labels=education_bachelor_summary$label) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1) +
  labs(fill="Bachelor/ Vordiplom",x=NULL,y=NULL,title="",caption="") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())
```

In my own R session the labels are not cut off, so I'm afraid I cannot help you with that issue now. One thing you could try is looking at `par(mar=c(...))` which is used to increase whitespace surrounding the plot window (see `?par`)

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it to tonight.