# How to put percentage in each sector of pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
fifa_data %>% count(Nationality) %>% mutate(n=n/sum(n))
```

[image]

I would like to plot these figures in a pie chart and put the percentages as labels into each sector of the pie. However, all I manage is this:

[image]

Using this code:

```
fifa_data %>% count(Nationality) %>% 
    mutate(n=n/sum(n)) %>% 
    ggplot( aes(x="", y=n, fill=Nationality))+
           geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +  
           coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
           geom_text(aes(y = n, label = percent(n)), size=3)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(fifa_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(fifa_data, 20))`.

Comment: uploaded another image, please see

Comment: @PrabeenParida Please in the future post the *actual* data as shown by Rui, not just a picture of the data: we can’t load a picture into R to play around with it.

Comment: You can check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753943/6123824